# Concatenate column names in one column conditional on using mutate, across and case_when

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I would like to:

1. Use `across` and `case_when` to check if columns A1-A3 == 1
2. Concatenate the column names of the columns where A1-A3 == 1 and
3. mutate a new column with the concatenated column names

My dataframe:

```
df <- tribble(
~ID,    ~A1,    ~A2,    ~A3,
1, 0, 1, 1, 
2, 0, 1, 1, 
3, 1, 1, 1, 
4, 1, 0, 1, 
5, 0, 1, 0)
```

Desired Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
     ID    A1    A2    A3 New_Col 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
1     1     0     1     1 A2 A3   
2     2     0     1     1 A2 A3   
3     3     1     1     1 A1 A2 A3
4     4     1     0     1 A1 A3   
5     5     0     1     0 A2
```

So far I have tried:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(New_Col = across(A1:A3, ~ case_when(. == 1 ~ paste0("colnames(.)", collapse = " "))))
```

Not working Output:

```
     ID    A1    A2    A3 New_Col$A1  $A2         $A3        
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
1     1     0     1     1 NA          colnames(.) colnames(.)
2     2     0     1     1 NA          colnames(.) colnames(.)
3     3     1     1     1 colnames(.) colnames(.) colnames(.)
4     4     1     0     1 colnames(.) NA          colnames(.)
5     5     0     1     0 NA          colnames(.) NA
```

**What I want to learn:**

1. Is it possible to use `across` to check for conditions across multiple columns
2. If yes how looks the part after ~ of `case_when` to get the specific colnames
3. How can I get only one column after using `mutate`, `across` and `case_when` and not 3 like here.

I thought I already was able to master this task, but somehow I lost it...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use `across` with `case_when` you can do -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(A1:A3, ~case_when(. == 1 ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  unite(New_Col, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ')

#    ID    A1    A2    A3 New_Col 
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
#1     1     0     1     1 A2 A3   
#2     2     0     1     1 A2 A3   
#3     3     1     1     1 A1 A2 A3
#4     4     1     0     1 A1 A3   
#5     5     0     1     0 A2
```

`across` creates 3 new columns named `new_A1`, `new_A2` and `new_A3` with the column name if the value is 1 or `NA` otherwise. Using `unite` we combine the 3 columns into one `New_col`.

---

Also we can use `rowwise` with `c_across` -

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(New_Col = paste0(names(.[-1])[c_across(A1:A3) == 1], collapse = ' '))
```

Comment: Ronak, instead of names() can we use cur_column here somehow directly?

Comment: You mean in `rowwise` or `group_by` `ID` right? I don't think we can do that since `cur_column` can be used within `across` only.

Comment: Yes, It returns this error only. Thanks for explaining :)

Answer (score 7):

without `rowwise`/ `across` you may also obtain same using `cur_data()`

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(new_col = paste0(names(df[-1])[as.logical(cur_data())], collapse = ' '))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   ID [5]
     ID    A1    A2    A3 new_col 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
1     1     0     1     1 A2 A3   
2     2     0     1     1 A2 A3   
3     3     1     1     1 A1 A2 A3
4     4     1     0     1 A1 A3   
5     5     0     1     0 A2
```

---

a `.` instead of `df` inside mutate will also do

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(new_col = paste0(names(.[-1])[as.logical(cur_data())], collapse = ' '))
```

Comment: Awesome Anil ji and Ronak, Have one query, here `cur_data` is each group, will it work even if there are more than 1 row for each group? Because I tried `as.logical(df[-1])` and expecting a DF of `TRUE` and `FALSE` but got this error: `Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'`. And what's the difference between `cur_data` and `cur_group`

Comment: Hi @KarthikS, you may call me Anil, see some explanation [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html).  `cur_data` returns the current data (grouped of course) and `cur_group` represents group keys.  So `cur_data` will return binary values here and `cur_group` will return ids.  Hope this is clear

Answer (score 4):

Using `base R`

```
df$New_Col <- apply(df[-1], 1, \(x) paste(names(x)[as.logical(x)], collapse=' '))
df$New_Col
#[1] "A2 A3"    "A2 A3"    "A1 A2 A3" "A1 A3"    "A2"
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(New_Col = across(A1:A3, ~ c('', cur_column())[. + 1] ) %>% 
                       invoke(str_c, .))
```

Answer (score 3):

One option involving also `purrr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(New_Col = pmap_chr(across(-ID), 
                           ~ paste(names(c(...))[which(c(...) == 1)], collapse = " ")))

     ID    A1    A2    A3 New_Col 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
1     1     0     1     1 A2 A3   
2     2     0     1     1 A2 A3   
3     3     1     1     1 A1 A2 A3
4     4     1     0     1 A1 A3   
5     5     0     1     0 A2
```